# How can i move downward in file?

Tags: c++, c

I can read lines or characters from file. How can i move downward and left or right in a file ?

1. You will start from the top and move downwards to an adjacent number as in below.
2. You are only allowed to walk downwards and diagonally.
3. You can only walk over NON PRIME NUMBERS.

   ```
        *1 
       *8 4
      2 *6 9
     8 5 *9 3
   ```

So i need to read firstly 1, then 8, then 6, then 9. But i dont know how can i read characters below.

Comment: Files are sequential sequences of bytes.  The concepts of "up" and "down" are solely a matter of how you interpret the data.  To go down, you simply need to figure out how far forward you need to go, which is a matter of your interpretation of the data.

Comment: Read each line as a sequence of `int`. With each row read you already know the ordinal position in the prior row. That position dictates which of the two possible position in the row-just-read that are viable. Think about the ordinals and a formula will likely pop into you head that can give you those possible ordinals (which are always consecutive, btw, so an (N,N+1) calculation, and therefore only N, is a huge hint)

Comment: You should be considering moving in a buffer, not a file.
Read the whole file at once, store it in a buffer and then check the buffer. Today we have gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: You are not forbidden to read any number you like from the file. Only the path you are asked to plot must only contain numbers which obey the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Files are stored sequentially, lines are illusion made by your text editor which divides them by '\n' character.
To *'move downwards'* in file, you need to store your position from the beginning of the line you are at and then skip to next '\n'

```
int result;
do {
    result = getc(f);
} while(result != '\n' && result != EOF);
```

and then move by that number `fseek(f, columnPosition, SEEK_CUR)` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/#parameters)).
That also answers your question how to *'move left or right'* in file:

```
fseek(f, -1, SEEK_CUR); //move left
fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR); //move right
```

Also you should consider storing the file in some kind of buffer, it's a lot easier to work with and reading from RAM is faster.
You could also put each line to array of string that way but that would be more difficult. This is how you do it:

```
//counting all characters
size_t bufferLen = 1;
while(fscanf(f, "%*c") != EOF)
    ++bufferLen;

//allocating space for your buffer
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(bufferLen * sizeof(char));

//starting over again
rewind(f);

//copying the file into the buffer
char c;
size_t i;
for(i = 0; fscanf(f, "%c", &c) != EOF; i++)
{
    buffer[i] = c;
}
buffer[i] = '\0';
```

And now you have a buffer to read from with direct access.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a code quickly.
The code contains all numbers marked with an asterisk. I used dynamic memory management while writing the code. But I think the numbers that I see later must be prime numbers. If you work a little on the code, I think you can write the full version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_file(const char *);

int main()
{
    read_file("test.txt");

}

void read_file(const char *filename) {
    int c;
    int flag = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if('*' == c) {
            flag = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(flag == 1 && ' ' != c) {
            count++;
            p = (int *)realloc(p, count*sizeof(int));
            p[count-1] = c - 48; 
        }

        if(' ' == c && count != 0 ) {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                printf("%d", p[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            flag = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    free(p);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: I will write a code according to the answer to this question.

Comment: You should use comments for this, answer sections is for answers you know...

Comment: Yes I know. But my reputation score is not enough.